# Nginx RTMP with on_play PHP auth

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp, clappr

I am having problem with the authentication part when user playing my streaming. I want only people who have registered to be able to play the streaming.

I am using the "on_play" directive in my nginx.conf setting.
Can anyone point out where do i go wrong?
It never actually call the auth page.

My setting...
192.168.10.207 is my streaming server
192.168.50.160  is my authentication server (my PC)

I am using clappr player...
and as the source i did

http://192.168.10.207/hls/stream.m3u8?username=rain&usertoken=397b57b2fe832bc18ff8318465fdc1c0

auth.php

```
$secret_key = "testkey123";
$username  =   $_POST['username'];
$usertoken    = $_POST['usertoken'];

$mytoken = strtolower(md5($username.$secret_key));

if ($token == $mytoken){
  header("HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted");
}else{
  header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
}
```

nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 8192;
                notify_method get;

                application hls {
                        live on;
                        meta copy;
                        hls on;
                        hls_fragment 1;
                        hls_playlist_length 2s;
                        hls_path /tmp/hls;
                        record off;
                        on_publish http://192.168.10.207/auth;    #protect uploading
                        on_play http://192.168.50.160/zeus/TP/auth;    #protect when playing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `on_play` and `on_publish` hooks are for the RTMP NetStream commands. `on_play` will only be called if trying to play the RTMP stream.

Comment: did some reading. since it will be played on HLS instead of RTMP protocol. the on_play will not run.

Comment: You could use the [ngx_http_auth_request_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) instead.